# Speed differences between calling directly and assigning to variable

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x

Situation: Consider the following two snippets of Python codes:-

Code 1:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top):
    for f in files:
        path = os.path.join(root, f)
        print(path)
```

Code 2:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top):
    for f in files:
        print(os.path,join(root,f))
```

Question: Will there any differences in terms of performance or speed if I do not declare the file path as a variable (assuming that I will only use it once -- if using more than once declaring the variable makes much more sense)

Comment: Likely not enough to matter, but if you care: https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html

Comment: You should **always** profile your code before optimizing it. Don't waste effort on trivial optimizations.

Comment: I tried to understand the definition of profiling on wikipedia but am still confused. Mind enlightening me? @aryamccarthy

Comment: Profiling is looking at how long code takes to run, plus where that time is spent. Take a look at [this](http://pynash.org/2013/03/06/timing-and-profiling/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to using [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) for simple benchmarking you can `pytest-benchmark`, which makes it super-simple to create a comparison, simply:

```
import os

def f1(top):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top):
        for f in files:
            path = os.path.join(root, f)
            print(path)

def f2(top):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top):
        for f in files:
            print(os.path.join(root, f))

def test_f1(benchmark):
    benchmark(f1, '~/tmp')

def test_f2(benchmark):
    benchmark(f2, '~/tmp')
```

Note: `~/tmp` contains 350 files/folders, YMMV. Running

```
python -m pytest test.py --benchmark-min-time=0.001 --benchmark-histogram=hist
```

Gives you nice data and a histogram:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------- benchmark: 2 tests ----------------------------------------------------------------------
Name (time in us)        Min               Max              Mean            StdDev            Median               IQR            Outliers(*)  Rounds  Iterations
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
test_f1               4.4811 (1.0)      8.6253 (1.0)      4.7941 (1.00)     0.3531 (1.0)      4.7141 (1.01)     0.2762 (1.31)            15;7     216        1000
test_f2               4.4967 (1.00)     9.3009 (1.08)     4.7773 (1.0)      0.5242 (1.48)     4.6838 (1.0)      0.2113 (1.0)             6;13     215        1000
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

[image: benchmark histogram]

As you can see, the difference is not significant considering the high variance.

Now if you are still curious, you can use [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) to show the bytecode that is being executed by CPython. This is a functionality of the CPython interpreter, which is the most common way to run python code:

```
In [1]: import os, dis

In [2]: def f1(top):
   ...:     for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top):
   ...:         for f in files:
   ...:             path = os.path.join(root, f)
   ...:             print(path)
   ...:             

In [3]: def f2(top):
   ...:     for root, dirs, files, in os.walk(top):
   ...:         for f in files:
   ...:             print(os.path.join(root, f))
   ...:             

In [4]: dis.dis(f1)
  2           0 SETUP_LOOP              60 (to 62)
              2 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (os)
              4 LOAD_ATTR                1 (walk)
              6 LOAD_FAST                0 (top)
              8 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             10 GET_ITER
        >>   12 FOR_ITER                46 (to 60)
             14 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          3
             16 STORE_FAST               1 (root)
             18 STORE_FAST               2 (dirs)
             20 STORE_FAST               3 (files)

  3          22 SETUP_LOOP              34 (to 58)
             24 LOAD_FAST                3 (files)
             26 GET_ITER
        >>   28 FOR_ITER                26 (to 56)
             30 STORE_FAST               4 (f)

  4          32 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (os)
             34 LOAD_ATTR                2 (path)
             36 LOAD_ATTR                3 (join)
             38 LOAD_FAST                1 (root)
             40 LOAD_FAST                4 (f)
             42 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             44 STORE_FAST               5 (path)

  5          46 LOAD_GLOBAL              4 (print)
             48 LOAD_FAST                5 (path)
             50 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             52 POP_TOP
             54 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           28
        >>   56 POP_BLOCK
        >>   58 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           12
        >>   60 POP_BLOCK
        >>   62 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             64 RETURN_VALUE

In [5]: dis.dis(f2)
  2           0 SETUP_LOOP              56 (to 58)
              2 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (os)
              4 LOAD_ATTR                1 (walk)
              6 LOAD_FAST                0 (top)
              8 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             10 GET_ITER
        >>   12 FOR_ITER                42 (to 56)
             14 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          3
             16 STORE_FAST               1 (root)
             18 STORE_FAST               2 (dirs)
             20 STORE_FAST               3 (files)

  3          22 SETUP_LOOP              30 (to 54)
             24 LOAD_FAST                3 (files)
             26 GET_ITER
        >>   28 FOR_ITER                22 (to 52)
             30 STORE_FAST               4 (f)

  4          32 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (print)
             34 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (os)
             36 LOAD_ATTR                3 (path)
             38 LOAD_ATTR                4 (join)
             40 LOAD_FAST                1 (root)
             42 LOAD_FAST                4 (f)
             44 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             46 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             48 POP_TOP
             50 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           28
        >>   52 POP_BLOCK
        >>   54 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           12
        >>   56 POP_BLOCK
        >>   58 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             60 RETURN_VALUE
```

So the first code does indeed produce more bytecode instructions.

Anyhow, you should consider [profiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-python-script) - make sure you look at parts of the code that are really relevant and avoid optimizing blindly.